# How to add custome/ java annotation in jdl JHipster Domain Language

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, jdl

With this code

```
entity Person {
   id   String 
   name String
   post String
}
```

It will give me like

```
@Id
private String id;

@Field("name")
private String name;
@Field("post")
private String post;
```

but i want like

```
@Id
private String id;

@Field("name")
@Indexed(name = "name",unique = true)
private String name;
@Field("post")
private String post;
```

And this thing i have to do automatically, while importing jdl it should created automatically.
How can i do that?

I read about custome annotation in jhipster but not getting how should i implement it.

Comment: As far as I know, custom annotations require you to write a blueprint to process them to generate the code you want. You may not want to spend this effort for something that you can easily do by modifying generated code manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the validator of jdl, in your case `unique`.

like this:

```
entity Person {
   id   String,
   name String unique,
   post String
}
```

Comment: This is useful because it adds "unique=true" on `@Column` annotation but it will not generate `@Indexed` and unfortunately the original poster did not describe from which package it came from. So we have no idea about what this annotation does.